# How is this interface and class being implemented?

Tags: java, jaxb

I am fairly new in this field.

Here is a code snippet:

JAXBContext jobj = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

```
Marshaller mobj = jobj.createMarshaller();   

Employee emp1=new Employee(1,"Jordan",50000);  
  
mobj.marshal(emp1, new FileOutputStream("employee.xml"));
```

Now I know JAXBContext  is an abstract class and  Marshaller  is an interface.

Now  how can createMarshaller()(Return type Marshaller) return a Marshaller object?  Is JAXBContext implementing Marshaller? Even if implementing then how it is returning the object? Cuz I have tried to implement an Interface in a class and then created a method that returns the object of that Interface but it was throwing error.

Tried to simulate:

Interface:
public interface

```
 Marshall {
    
    public Marshall marshaller();
    
    public int m();

}
```

Class:

```
public class JaxB implements Marshall{
    
    
    @Override
    public Marshall marshaller() {
        
        return new Marshall(); //error
        
    }

    public int m(){
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Can you please correct my Class?

Comment: `createMarshaller` evidently instantiates some class that implements the interface, and returns the instance. Any instance of an interface is an instance of some class that implements the interface. That is how interfaces work.

Comment: I have tried to implement an Interface in a class and then created a method that returns the object of that Interface but it was throwing error

Comment: Then in the code where you were trying to do that, you did it wrong.

Comment: Ok plz show us your code then what have you tried and from which line the error comes from

Comment: You mean `return new JaxB();` in the new code you posted. Though it would make more sense if there was some _other_ class implementing the interface, and the method returned an instance of _that_ class.

Comment: @khelwood Can you provide an example?

Comment: @DavidJohnson OK. I've posted it as an answer.

Comment: @DavidJohnson hey, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367849/recursion-returning-arrayindexoutofbound-exception/66368607#66368607

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to have a method return an instance of an interface:

```
interface Foo {}

class FooImplementation implements Foo {}

class FooFactory {
    Foo getFoo() {
        return new FooImplementation();
    } 
}
```

Comment: But createMarshaller() returns a Marshaller object [Marshaller mobj = jobj.createMarshaller();] which is an Interface.But FooFactory  is returning  FooImplementation  object not Foo. So the simulation is not woking as expected.

Comment: `FooImplementation` implements `Foo`. So an instance of `FooImplementation` is an instance of `Foo`. **That is how interfaces work.** The method that returns `Marshall` must return an instance of a class that implements `Marshall`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a method inside that class and add the return statement with the parameters you want to send and then create an object in the Class you want to call the method which will receive the output of the method

Comment: I really appriciate your answer. It is intuitive. Could you please provide example code?