# Recursion returning ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

Tags: java, recursion

```java
public class Check {

    static int count = 0;
    static final int totw = 4;

    public static int minh(int books[][], int bookno, int totw, int wl, int l) {
        if (bookno > books.length)
            return l;

        int sidebyside = 99;
        int top = 99;

        if (books[bookno][0] <= wl)
            sidebyside = minh(books, bookno + 1, totw, totw - (books[bookno][0] + wl), Math.max(l, books[bookno][1]));
        
        top = minh(books, bookno + 1, totw, totw - books[bookno][0], l + books[bookno][1]);

        return Math.min(sidebyside, top);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] books = { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 3 }, { 2, 3 } };

        System.out.println(minh(books, 1, totw, 3, 1));
    }
}
```

Can you please assist or rectify me where I am actually doing wrong? I used 99 to simulate a very big number.
I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
> at Check.minh(Check.java:21)
> at Check.minh(Check.java:24)
> at Check.minh(Check.java:22)
> at Check.main(Check.java:37)

Here is the question link:https://leetcode.com/problems/filling-bookcase-shelves/

I know this is highly inefficient but I am just practising recursion thats all.

Comment: The condition is not  `if(bookno>books.length)` but   `if(bookno==books.length)` . 3 is not bigger than 3, but index 3 doesn't exist. Also, you start by the second position: `minh(books, 1, totw, 3, 1))` should be `minh(books, 0, totw, 3, 1))`

Comment: "bookno+1" could be the culprit that cause the OutOfBoundsException. Let's suppose bookno is 2 then bookno+1 = 3. Counting from 0 you have here 4 and your books has only 3 rows...

Comment: Thank you so much -aran and -Joe. Your suggestions were truly helpful and I got rid off the Outofbound exception. Now it seems my code is faulty but thats ok. Thank you guys.

Comment: -aran I intentionally started from the second position, as the first element can be placed without any constraint.